# What is the runway holding short line on Taxiway B between B2 and B3 at KFAT for RWY29L?

Tags: runways, faa, airport-markings

At Fresno Yosemite International Airport (KFAT), I was instructed to taxi to RWY 29L via B11, B from Signature Support. When passing B3 and approaching RWY 29L end, I noticed there is one holding short line between B2 and B3 and the next one is on B2, I was confused where to hold short for the instruction (hold at the first anyways).

The one between B2 and B3 seems extra, but it is a double-solid-double-dashed line, which is also shown the Google Map the same I observed. I am wondering how this can well-define a runway protection area? Meanwhile, the first holding short line (the one between B2 and B3) does not mark which runway it protects. I also suspect it should have been ILS protection marking instead.

- [Google Map Link to KFAT Airport](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Fresno+Yosemite+International+Airport/@36.7758536,-119.7203023,563m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x80945c1fe8a2ab03:0x6fd4faa840e5cec3!8m2!3d36.7758493!4d-119.7181083)

### [image: Google Map KFAT Airport]

[image]

### [FAA Airport Diagram for KFAT](http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/FAT/APD/AIRPORT+DIAGRAM/pdf)

### [image]

Answer (score 3):

That’s a hold line for aircraft taxiing on Bravo while large aircraft are departing Rwy 29L to prevent aircraft from taxiing behind the blast pad for 29L and potentially being tossed around by the jet blast from the departing aircraft.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Do you mean the hold line on taxiway B (b/w B2 and B3) or the one on B2?

Comment: Hold traffic cleared to taxi to 29R short of Bravo 2 for a departing aircraft on 29L.

Comment: It makes sense that Line 1 is a hold line for Taxiway B2. I am still surprised to see a hold short line is marked when both sides are movement areas.

Comment: If atc wants you to hold at the first line, how would they say it? Would they say “hold short of B2” or what?